# What is an assertion error in Microsoft Visual Studio? and unhandled exception access violation?

Tags: c, h.264, assertions

What are assertion errors? I have read that it might be caused by a NULL value of a pointer being passed to function. I am reading a file from Visual Studio and I am sure this file exists. How can there be an assertion error?

Also, I have found an assert statement in my c program

```
assert(pred_dir<=2);
```

this code was downloaded from the internet (the reference software of h.264 video codec) from the internet and I am not quite sure how i would get an error like this. Sorry I could not post the source code because it is too big and consists of four projects. I only modified the code to read a textfile and got this error.

Also, what is an unhandled exception, access violation error?

Comment: from the linux man page "assert - abort the program if assertion is false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29) is a condition that you, as a programmer, expect to be unequivocally true at a given point in the program. Many programming languages give you a way to assert a condition, and you, as a programmer, can use assertions to find and diagnose many problems before they happen.

For example, if at a specific point in your program, you expect a variable called `a` to be `0`, you can write:

```
assert(a == 0);
```

and if during runtime, `a` is not `0` at that specific part of the program, you will get an artificial error, and the debugger will stop right there so you can diagnose your problem, and understand why `a` is not `0`.

A very common assertion goes like

```
assert(some_pointer != NULL); // We already checked this before
```

In your specific example, a variable called `pred_dir` is expected to be less than or equal than `2`. If you're getting an assertion error in there, it means that for some reason, `pred_dir` was greater than `2`. Since the rest of the program is not expecting this, it makes no sense to keep on going, and the program will stop right there.

Please remember that assertions are a debugging aid to help you implement "sanity checks", and not as a way to display an error to a user. As such, you are encouraged to use lots of them when making your program, to make sure that all your assumptions about the state of your program are correct. If your program is correct, assertions should never stop the program.

Since assertions are a debugging aid, checking them makes no sense when you release your program for distribution to users. Therefore, many programmers turn off assertion checking when doing so. Many environments like Visual Studio automatically turn them off when creating a release build.

Check the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29), as it explains assertions in much more detail.

If an assertion is triggered on a released product, or a third-party library, it most likely means that there is an error in that program. If you are able to reproduce the problem, please report it to the author of the program.

Comment: Thank you! will assertions be evaluated if a run the .exe file of the program or the command prompt? The program breaks unexpectedly. I am not sure whether the program I downloaded has the error since it already have 18 versions. And I am not sure if the error is in crt0msg.c in :\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\crt\src\crt0msg.c where the program breaks since according to what I read the program will break very far from the point which caused the error. I do not know what I am doing wrong. But thank you for you help!

Comment: @wangdongchaine: Yes and no. Assertions are a part of the program, so they will be evaluated regardless of how the program is executed (command prompt or debugger, or whatever other way the program is executed). However, when a program is sent for distribution, assertion checking is usually turned off by the programmer, because they are meant to be debugging aids, and of little use to regular users of the program. It is certainly possible to ship a program with assertion checking on, but that doesn't really help the user much, so they're usually turned off.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: What are assertion errors?

If a programmer believe that a condition is so vital that it must always be true, and should not continue execution if the condition is found to be false, he can make an assertion. Which you posted a fine example of, if the condition (pred_dir<=2) returns true, then execution is continued as normal, but if it returns false, then the execution is halted and some indication is shown as to which assertion returned false.

Edit: Assertions can be used to debug your code or as stated simply used to halt execution if something VERY wrong happened.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be caused because the Temp folder on your computer has read-only access control specified. Therefore, the Visual Studio .NET or Visual Studio 2005 Setup application cannot copy temporary installation files to your local hard disk.

Solution : To resolve this problem, remove the read-only access control for your Temp folder. To do this, follow these steps:

a) Locate the Temp folder on your computer.

b) Note Typically, this folder is located in C:\Documents and Settings\User Name\Local Settings, where User Name is your user name.

c) Right-click Temp, and then click Properties.

d) Under Attributes, click to clear the check box for Read-only.

**Note** : The Confirm Attribute Changes dialog box may appear (this behavior depends on the contents of your Temp folder). If this dialog box appears, click Apply changes to this folder, sub-folders and files, and then click OK.

e) Click OK.

Comment: For unhandled exception and access violation error, please let me know when you get these errors while installing any version or while running any script.

Comment: I'll try this one! and what do you mean by "please let me know when you get these errors while installing any version or while running any script"?

Comment: I mean when do you get the error : Unhandled exception or Access violation error

Comment: apply changes to this foler, subfolders and files?

Comment: I'm not sure. I get confused with these two errors. are they similar? sometimes i get the unhandled exception and sometimes the assertion error. but the assertion error is the most common. do you have any knowledge on JM or h.264 reference software?

Comment: can you please explain why i have to remove the read only access control in simpler terms?

Comment: Please view this website. You will get resolution regarding all the errors of Microsoft Visual Studio http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814697

Comment: removing the read only access did not solve the problem. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. but thank you for your answer!